# mongo DB + java + jsp (Tomcat)

Tags: java, jsp, mongodb, tomcat

1) В сервлете выгребаем все уникальные значения user_id:

```
 List varTextA = anycollection.distinct("user_id");
//передаем их в таблицу:
        request.setAttribute("textA", varTextA);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

2) Далее таблица в index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>test table</p>

<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <th width="20%" style="background: lightyellow">User ID</th>
        <th width="20%" style="background: lightblue">etc name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="80%" style="background: lightyellow">${textA}</td>
        <td width="80%" style="background: lightblue"> etc value </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

3) В итоге в ячейку таблицы ${textA} собираются все уникальные значения и выводятся в виде единой строки в формате ["some_id_01" , "some_id_02" , "some_id_n"] - что достаточно информативно но слабочитаемо для обычного юзера.

Вопрос: как отобразить в той же ячейке все эти значения - каждое с новой строки (или каждое в новой ячейке)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключите стандартную библиотеку тегов и используйте тег `forEach`.

Для этого понадобится пакет `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl`

Зависимость maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

В начале jsp страницы указать:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

После этого можно использовать теги библиотеки. Например:

```
<c:forEach var="element" items="${textA}">
   <%--Тело цикла. В вашем случае тут будут повторяться строки таблицы--%>
   <p>${element}
</c:forEach>
```

[Тут](http://java-online.ru/jsp-jstl.xhtml) можно почитать про другие теги jstl

Comment: Спасибо огромное ! С применением выше описанного все отрабатывает коррект и именно так как требовалось :)